# Would it be possible to develop Kodachrome in color?

Tags: color, developing, kodak

I own a lot of undeveloped Kodachrome II rolls from the 60s from family members that are no longer with me. They have been in storage for a long time and I am looking to have them developed in color. I am well aware that color processing for Kodachrome ended in late 2010. Does anyone still process Kodachrome in color? Can I do this myself? What chemicals would I need? The cost is not a concern, and I have a lot of spare time. Any help will be appreciated, and I won't value comments or answers telling me to "give up the dream".

Comment: Part of the difficulty is that Eastman Kodak no longer makes the very specific chemicals needed for others to develop Kodachrome.

Comment: With respect, whenever this comes up, I simply wonder: Why did you wait so long?!

Comment: Kodachrome gets its colours from colour couplers. The different emulsion layers can be developed with otherwise normal developers similar to DK-50 for black & white single-layer emulsions. The first developer is a b&w developer. The second developer contains the couplers that take effect within the c, m, & y layers. In the meantime, keep your film desiccated and frozen to delay the tendency for the the latent image to fade and the edges and ends to fog from environmental contaminants. Good Luck.

Comment: Any updates? My dad just passed away and I found some undeveloped Kodachrome slide film...

Answer (score 5):

At the moment I don't believe there is any way to develop your Kodachrome, either yourself or commercially. It's a complicated process that never AFAIK was able to be done at home. There were rumors that Kodak Alaris would consider restarting manufacturing of Kodachrome, but Kodak later said that that would be expensive and environmentally problematic, so unlikely to happen.

I know you specified color, but if that fails, [some people](https://www.lomography.com/magazine/255669-processing-a-kodachrome-64-in-b-and-w) have had success developing Kodachrome to create B&W negatives...

Comment: I have had an idea. It would develop to "color", but not really. Kodachrome is developed in several steps. The dyes are not in the film, but are added one by one in the development process. So, my idea is to replicate that process of adding dyes, but instead of trying to add Red, Green, Blue dyes, add just Black, Black and Black. (For instance with Caffenol.) So what you say, why replicate the complicated steps of adding the 3 layers if all you get in the end is a BW image?! Well... imagine scanning the film once **between each step**. You'd extract the *amount* of RGB... and could rebuild it.

Answer (score 5):

While officially the last roll was developed 7years ago, as of a few months ago, there appears to be one guy who sort of figured out how develop Kodachrome.  He might do it for you with no guarantees.  Check out the following and the best of luck with where they lead:

https://www.facebook.com/groups/119931904758842/permalink/1226654574086564/

https://www.etsy.com/listing/507743913/beta-kodachrome-color-development

Comment: article in Popular Photography about this last January: [Someone Figured Out a Process For Developing Kodachrome Film In Color](http://www.popphoto.com/someone-figured-out-process-for-developing-kodachrome-film-in-color)

Answer (score 4):

Kodachrome is very much developable in just about any B&W developer. I've had luck with 64ISO Kodachrome in D-76 (1+1) and in Caffenol. I'm trying some Kodachrome II which is 25ISO in D-76. Dev time for the 64ISO Kodachrome in 1+1 D-76 was 6:30 at 20* Celsius, fix time was 7:15 (because you can't over-fix) and I finished the rinse with a little bit of Ilford wetting agent to promote even drying. I was happily surprised with the results. Though theoretically you stop down when shooting expired film, I got good results shooting at the box ISO of 64 and I'm shooting my Kodachrome II at the box speed of 25.

I too have a crapton of Kodachrome K-64 and Kodachrome II laying around making my experiments doable.

I've tried C-41 and have been disappointed every time. **I'd stick to B&W if I were you, and play around with it to get the best possible results.**

Answer (score 1):

"Kelly-Shane Fuller of Piratelogy Studios has been experimenting...and experimenting...and experimenting with processing Kodachrome in color. And he's done it."

https://shootfilmco.com/blogs/shoot-film-co/kodachrome-processed-in-color-seriously

Comment: That's a very qualified "he's done it." He's certainly made some progress, but his results are far from perfect. You can follow some of his progress here: 
http://www.apug.org/forum/index.php?threads/kodachrome.136992/page-4#post-1873982

Answer (score 1):

http://www.thecamerashop.com/imagecenter/slides.html.  Advertises that they still develop Kodachrome.